# react-pixi is giving a error with useTick

Tags: reactjs, pixi.js

Im having some trouble with the use of useTick in react with react-pixi

getting a error:

> No Context found with `PIXI.Application`. Make sure to wrap component
> with `AppProvider`

So i tried to wrap the AppProvider, but that did´nt do it.

So here is my code for the specific component that´s import react-pixi:

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'

import {  ParticleContainer, useApp, useTick, Stage, Sprite, Container } from '@inlet/react-pixi'
import { Application } from 'pixi.js'

let scale = { x: 0.5, y: 0.5 };

const TryPixi = () => {
    const app = useApp();
 
    const [itemRotation, setItemRotation] = useState(0);

  
    useTick(delta => {
      setItemRotation(itemRotation + 1) 
      })
    
   
    return (
     
        <Stage width={139} height={140} options={{ transparent: true }}>
            <Container   
            x={70} 
            y={70} 
            >
            <Sprite 
            image="../../assets/ninja.png" 
            
            anchor={[0.5, 0.5]} 
            scale={scale} 
            rotation={0.5}
            />
            </Container>
        </Stage>
    
    

    );
};

export default TryPixi;
```

And call the component like this from another component:

```
<AppProvider><TryPixi /></AppProvider>
```

I have tried with and without the AppProvider, and yes the AppProvideris imported :-) Hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 4):

You can only use `useTick` on component that returns only the animated object.

```
const Ninja = () => {
    const [itemRotation, setItemRotation] = useState(0);

  
    useTick(delta => {
      setItemRotation(itemRotation + 1) 
      })
    
   
    return (
        <Sprite 
        image="../../assets/ninja.png" 
            
        anchor={[0.5, 0.5]} 
        scale={scale} 
        rotation={0.5}
        />
    );
};

const TryPixi = () => {
    return (
        <Stage width={139} height={140} options={{ transparent: true }}>
            <Container   
            x={70} 
            y={70} 
            >
                <Ninja />
            </Container>
        </Stage>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it's work for me.
I'm using react and pixi-react components.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I could understand from [Stage component source code](https://github.com/inlet/react-pixi/blob/master/src/stage/index.js), it creates its own application in `componentDidMount` here [lines 115 - 121]:

```
this.app = new Application({
  width,
  height,
  view: this._canvas,
  ...options,
  autoDensity: options?.autoDensity !== false,
})
```

It then provides this app to its children via wrapping the children in `AppProvider` component [lines 216 - 217]:

```
const { children } = this.props
return <AppProvider value={this.app}>{children}</AppProvider>
```

This means you can use the hooks that depend on this context only inside the children components of `Stage`, not in the Stage component itself; because [useApp hook](https://github.com/inlet/react-pixi/blob/master/src/hooks/useApp.js) uses this context, and [useTick hook](https://github.com/inlet/react-pixi/blob/master/src/hooks/useTick.js) uses the useApp hook.
So, your wrapper component that renders `TryPixi` should be like this:

```
<Stage><TryPixi /></Stage>
```

And then you call the hooks from inside `TryPixi` component.